# np loadtxt return array instead of array using paragraph as delimiter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files, numpy-ndarray

I need to load a txt file into a np.array, in which 
[data are in N several lines, that is, separated by paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9wlQ.png). When I use np.loadtxt it returns a **np.ndarray** with shape (N,). I want it to return a **np.array** with "shape" (N) (in other words, a simple 1D array). How can I do this? I am also willing to upload data as ndarray and then convert it to array if there is no other way...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What do you mean? When I use `np.array([1,2,3,4]).shape` I get `(4,)` - what do expect to happen differently? This is the a 1D array.

Comment: Yes, but after import the text, eg a=np.loadtxt('[file directory]'), and then type(a) i get ndarray instead of array

Comment: `np.array` returns an `ndarray`. The first is a function, the second a class. That's why I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: If the last comment was not clear, try looking at `type(np.array([]))`.

Answer (score 0):

With a text file with one number per line:

```
In [356]: cat stack60588161.csv                                                                
1
2
3
4
5
```

`loadtxt` produces a 1d numpy array:

```
In [357]: data = np.loadtxt('stack60588161.csv')                                               
In [358]: data                                                                                 
Out[358]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
In [359]: data.shape                                                                           
Out[359]: (5,)
```

I can force it to create a 2d array:

```
In [361]: data = np.loadtxt('stack60588161.csv',ndmin=2)                                       
In [362]: data                                                                                 
Out[362]: 
array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.],
       [5.]])
In [363]: data.shape                                                                           
Out[363]: (5, 1)
```

This is more like the conventional multicolumn csv load.